# Android Widget Bundle getString showing null

Tags: android, string, android-intent, widget, bundle

I'm trying to get a widget to show text which it receives via an intent.

When I build the app and use breakpoints in my Widget class to follow the code, the class receives the string without any problems. While in debugging I add the widget to the home screen and using breakpoints I follow the code again but this time it shows the string as null.

Build and run app -> String = "Hello", Add Widget -> String = null

My Activity class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ArtistWidget.class);
        String test = "Hello";
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("artist", test);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In My widget class:

```
public class ArtistWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> artistList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private String data;    
    RemoteViews remoteViews;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    


    data = intent.getStringExtra("artist");


    super.onReceive(context, intent);
  }



@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
    {      

        ComponentName artistWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.artist_widget );
        artistWidget = new ComponentName( context, ArtistWidget.class );
        remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_textview, "T" + data + "D");  
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( artistWidget, remoteViews );   
    }
```

In the onReceive function I tried:

```
    getPrevData = intent.getExtras();
    data = getPrevData.getString("artist"); //Crashes here
```

But it crashes when I put the widget on the home screen.

Comment: Please include the logcat stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the string directly?

```
intent.getStringExtra("artist");
```